# Default packet size and data rate of omnet++

Tags: omnet++

How can i find the default data rate and default packet size in OMNET++? Basically, i simulate a protocol without consider the value of cmessage. So, i want to know the default length of cmessage and default data rate.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by `data rate`? Do you consider the data rate of a channel?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, `cMessage` does not have length field. `cPacket` (subclass of `cMessage`) has the length. According to [OMNeT++ Simulation Library](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cPacket.html):

> cPacket adds length (measured in bits or bytes), bit error flag, and encapsulation capability to cMessage. Length and bit error flag are significant when the packet travels through a cDatarateChannel or another channel that supports data rate and/or error modelling.

If one creates a new instance of `cPacket` using constructor without arguments, it will have the length equal to zero. However, usually the length of that packet is set in constructor or later using `setBitLength()` or `setByteLength()` methods. And there is no default length value - it depends on what protocol/frame/packet is modeling.